# Why cant I create heap out of python list

Tags: python, heapq

```
import heapq
x=[1,4,2]
heapq.heapify(x)
print(x)
```

The result I get is [1,4,2], what am I missing?[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no special heap data structure in Python. A heap is just a list for which the ["heap invariant"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#theory) holds, i.e.

> Heaps are arrays for which `a[k] <= a[2*k+1]` and `a[k] <= a[2*k+2]` for all `k`, counting elements from 0. For the sake of comparison, non-existing elements are considered to be infinite. The interesting property of a heap is that `a[0]` is always its smallest element.

As long as this holds (which `heapify` ensures), `heappop` can quickly pop the smallest element and replace it with the next-smallest. In the case of your list, the heap invariant was already fulfilled, despite the list not being fully sorted, so `heapify` did not change anything. Still, if you `heappop` the elements, they will come out in sorted order.